# Server side module not found on React JS

Tags: reactjs, server

I am working on a react app which has a server side. Whenever, I start the server I received an error,

> server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon index.js

```
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../update/decorateUpdateWithVersionKey'
Require stack:
- D:\Project\src\Server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\model\castBulkWrite.js
- D:\Project\src\Server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js
- D:\Project\src\Server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js
- D:\Project\src\Server\node_modules\mongoose\index.js
- D:\Project\src\Server\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:121:18)
```

Any idea how to solve this.

Thank you